# Nginx config file not reloading

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm trying to dabble in Nginx and making my first server thingie, but it's not working. Here is my config file

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        location / {
            root ~/42cursus/ft_server/tests/www;
        }

        location /images/ {
            root ~/42cursus/ft_server/tests;
        }
    }
    include servers/*;
}
```

I've been following this beginner's guide : https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html. The only thing I did different was delete the commented lines in the default config file in order for it to be clearer to me.

Whenever I send nginx -s reload, I get a "signal process started" added to my error.log, and trying to access the site via localhost just shows [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lImOw.png).

Could someone help me, keeping in mind that I'm on a school computer and can't use SUDO ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Added "listen 80;" to my server block, and now I get a 404 instead of nothing, at least that's progress !